# Row doesnot exists in DB- Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

We have a dataset **dsActualCost** which fetches query value: *MonthName* in one column and *Cost* in another.
We have a code to display data in table format.

```
 For MonthIndex = 0 To dsMonth.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
   Dim tdMonthlycost As New TableCell
   If dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
     If IsDBNull(dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows(MonthIndex).Item(1)) Then         
           tdMonthlycost.Text = 0
      Else
           tdMonthlycost.Text = dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows(MonthIndex).Item(1)
      End If
    Else
      tdMonthlycost.Text = 0
    End If
       trBody.Cells.Add(tdMonthlycost)
  Next
```

This code works fine when
**we have data in all rows

we have no data at all**

But it gives exception for all other cases.
I tried to debug and issue arises when it searches for any row which is not available in DB.

Say the dataset has only 2 rows for Feb month,so when it executes line
 IsDBNull(dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows(2).Item(1))
It throws Db null exception.

please suggest how should i handle it. the loop will run for 12 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code now. Do let me know if you have any suggestions:

```
Dim Flag As Integer = 0  
For MonthIndex = 0 To dsMonth.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1  
 Dim tdMonthly As New TableCell  
     Dim CostMonth As Integer  
     Dim CostValue As Integer  
     If (dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) Then  
          If (Flag <> dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows.Count) Then  
               CostMonth = dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows(Flag).Item(1)  
                CostValue = dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows(Flag).Item(0)  
                 If (dsMonth.Tables(0).Rows(MonthIndex).Item(0) = CostMonth Or (dsMonth.Tables(0).Rows(MonthIndex).Item(0) - 1 = CostMonth)) Then  
                      tdMonthly.Text = CostValue  
                      Flag = Flag + 1  
                 Else  
                      tdMonthly.Text = 0  
                  End If  
             Else  
                   tdMonthly.Text = 0  
             End If  
         Else  
             tdMonthly.Text = 0  
        End If  
        trBody.Cells.Add(tdMonthly)  
Next
```

The month in dsMonth dataset is an integer and shows only even number( like Jan-2, Feb-4 etc). But the month in dsActual shows either of 1,2 for Jan and 3,4 for feb. That is the reason I had put

```
 If (dsMonth.Tables(0).Rows(MonthIndex).Item(0) = CostMonth 
    Or (dsMonth.Tables(0).Rows(MonthIndex).Item(0) - 1 = CostMonth))
```

Please let me know your suggestions if any.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be checking:

```
If dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 And
   MonthIndex < dsActualCost.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```

Without that check, you could index out of the Rows array if `MonthIndex` refers to a position that isn't present.

Comment: If the monthIndex loop reaches 2 but dsActualCost dataset has value only for September,October and November(No data  for previous months), the loop would display that data in January, February and March. Other months will show 0.

Comment: @RMN - You still need to check to make sure MonthIndex isn't out of range in dsActualCost. You said you were getting an exception, that may be the reason. If you index out of an array, that will cause an exception.

Comment: Yep you are correct and the way you told is also correct. But when i want to put data of Month jan in first cell and april in 4th cell. What kind of loop should i use ? The loop you told will only not allow exception. But when i want to pick up value for a particular month, then how should i proceed ?

Comment: @RMN - If you have data in Jan and Apr, then how many rows are you going to have in dsActualCost.Tables(0)?  Would you just have 2 rows, one for Jan and Apr? If that's the case, I think you will need to move your inner loop to another loop and handle it separately.